# Navigation not working after upgrading to Blender 2.79 from 2.78

Tags: interface

After recent upgrading 2.79 none of navigation controls are working properly, eg. instead of going through camera perspective with **num 0** it opens a layer.

Same is with changing from perp to ortho with num 5. I tried resetting input to **Blender** and also tried loading factory defaults.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your numeric keypad is enabled (press the 
<kbd>Num Lock</kbd> key).

Also check that you are using the default blender shortcuts: Open the **System Preferences** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) and in the input section reset the preset to **Blender**

[image]

Alternatively you can set the keyboard configuration at the splash screen (where it reads **"Interaction"**
:

[image]

Or just use File>**Load Factory Settings** on the main menu.

Comment: Tried both the solutions and still nothing happens but when i roll back to 2.78 those same shortcuts work

Comment: If it works with older versions and not on new ones it could be a bug. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports